# How can I get an integer from an RFID tag from Arduino Mega to NodeMCU 1.0 over serial communication?

Tags: esp8266, arduino-mega, softwareserial, rfid

I want the number from an RFID tag read by a reader connected to an Arduino Mega to end up as a string on a NodeMCU connected to the Mega. I am trying to confirm that the string is on the NodeMCU using the serial monitor. With the code below, the serial monitor for the NodeMCU prints "receivedChars:" only and not the number from the tag. What am I missing?

Code for Arduino Mega

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>

#define SS_PIN 53
#define RST_PIN 5
MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);   // Create MFRC522 instance.


String sent = "n";
String UID_string = ""; 

void setup() {

    SPI.begin();            // Init SPI bus
    mfrc522.PCD_Init(); // Init MFRC522 card
    Serial.begin(115200); // Initialize serial communications with the PC
    Serial.println("Running Version Jan5a");
    Serial.println("Mega:Serial Monitor initialized at 115200 baud...");
    Serial3.begin(9600); // Initialize serial communication with ESP
    Serial.println("Mega:Serial Port 3 for NodeMCU initialized at 9600 baud...");
    Serial.println("Mega: Scan PICC to see UID and type...");
}

////////


void SendUIDtoESP() {

if (sent == "n") {
  Serial.print("sent= ");
  Serial.print(sent);
  //if (UID_string.length() > 0)  {
  UID_string = "Hello World"; //test line
  Serial3.print("<");
  Serial3.print(String(UID_string));
  Serial3.print(">");
  Serial.println("Mega:Sending UID string to ESP");
  sent = "y";
  Serial.print("after sending, sent= ");
  Serial.print(sent);
//  } else {
 //   Serial.println("Mega: Error: UID-string not set yet!");
  //}

}
} // end Send UID to ESP

void loop {
SendUIDtoESP() ;
}
```

**Code for NodeMCU**

```
int numChars = 0;
String receivedChars = "";
boolean newData = false;
String tag = "";
unsigned long lastTime = 0;
unsigned long timerDelay = 5000;


SoftwareSerial s(D1,D2);// assign pins to send data to and receive data from NodeMCU to Arduino Mega rx, tx

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600); 
    s.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("NodeMCU: Waiting for serial connection with Mega to be available over s");
  while (! s.available() >0){
    Serial.print("."); // waiting
    return;
  }
  Serial.println("NodeMCU: Looks like Mega is available."); 
} // end void setup

 void recvWithStartEndMarkers() { //listen to Mega
    static boolean recvInProgress = false;
    static byte ndx = 0;
    char startMarker = '<';
    char endMarker = '>';
    char rc;
 
    while (s.available() > 0 && newData == false) {
        rc = s.read();

        if (recvInProgress == true) {
            if (rc != endMarker) {
                Serial.println(rc);
                receivedChars[ndx] = rc;
                ndx++;
                if (ndx >= numChars) {
                    ndx = numChars - 1;
                }
            }
            else {
                receivedChars[ndx] = '\0'; // terminate the string
                recvInProgress = false;
                ndx = 0;
                newData = true;     
            }
        }
        else if (rc == startMarker) {
          Serial.println("startMarker received");
            recvInProgress = true;
        }     
    }
} // end recvWithStartEndMarkers()

void loop() {
recvWithStartEndMarkers();
}
```

Comment: why the Mega? NodeMcu has SPI too

Comment: what is this?: `String UID_string =  (String)UID_unsigned;`

Comment: I think I took the block containing that line from here: https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid/issues/63#issuecomment-66874814

Comment: I'm using the NodeMCU for Wifi for the Mega (not reflected here to cut down on code length); I'm using the Mega because I plan on adding an unknown number of components down the road and think I need the ports.

Comment: determine if the serial comm actually works as expected ... start with simple `hello world` sketch

Comment: @jsotola are you suggesting testing the Mega sending 'hello world' to the NodeMCU?

Comment: yes, that would make certain that the two devices are able to communicate ... one other thing, when printing `receivedChars`, print the length of `receivedChars` also ... some characters are nonprinting

Comment: @jsotola Thanks for pointing me back to this level of basics. It does not seem to be working with hardcoded Uid_string = "Hello World" in the Mega code (nothing seems to be coming through, and no value for length is prining). I'll work on that. I read somewhere that using the SerialMonitor on the NodeMCU's USB micro-B port could interfere with the serial communications (ESP D1, D2 / Mega 15,14) with the Mega. Might that be an issue here?

Comment: Your nodemcu code would print "receivedChars" also, if nothing was received. You might wanna move that code into the if statement of the end marker (so only printing, when a full message was received). How did you connect the mega and the nodemcu?

Comment: @jsotola Update: I have focused on getting just 'Hello World!' to transmit and displayed on Serial Monitor for the ESP, and that is now working. I have removed the RFID section because I think the real challenge is converting a character array to string on the ESP, not the RFID reading on the Mega. The serial monitor for the ESP, however, prints "startMarker received" on one line, and then each character of "Hello World!" on a different line. If someone can help me to get 'Hello World!' on the ESP as a string I can append to a URL as a parameter, I should be set (I think).